# Render js if variable length is 0 (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am defining a variable in my controller method. I want to render js if the size of the variable is zero.

My code is:

```
def department
  @department = Department.all
end
```

when the above method is called department.html.erb is rendered right now

I want or do something like this:

```
def department
  @department = Department.all
  if @department.count > 0
    render :html => html-template-name
  else
    render :js => "alert('No department available');"
  end
end
```

This should render html if count is greater than 0 else should render js.
What should be the syntax of render html part?

Comment: you need to use "render template: "html-template" instead.

Comment: Are you making an AJAX request or normal html call ?

Comment: @GauravGupta.. yes that is the question

Answer (score 1):

`render html:` is not used to render a template.  it is used to render html.  example:

```
render html: "<strong>Not Found</strong>".html_safe
```

I believe you are looking for `render` or `render template:`

```
render "products/show"
```

or

```
render template: "products/show"
```

Docs: [Using Render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)